# How to receive mouse enter event from DOM element covered by other element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a jQuery project where I'm dragging an element by setting it's position to absolute and then listening to mouse motion to move the element around. This works perfectly, but then I'm trying to drag the element onto another element and the other element don't give me a mouse enter event when mouse enters. If the mouse position is not overlapped by an absolutely positioned element I receive the mouse enter event, but when I have the absolutely positioned element under the mouse I'm not receiving the event. I'm trying to do various drag and drop things with lists, maybe I'll check jQuery UI later, but I'd like to be able to do something simple.

Comment: I wrote a drag and drop plugin once, and found it this wasn't possible. The solution I came up with was to store the top, left, width and height of each droppable area, and test if the mouse position was within one of the multiple bounding boxes made by the stored dimensions.

Comment: I thought about that, but then I read somewhere that the event handler to the mouse motion event should execute as fast as possible since many events are generated. Do you find any slowdown of the page with your approach?

Comment: I don't, but this is with 2-3 droppable areas on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

set the z-index css property of the element.

check this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I'm not getting that to work on chrome, have you tried doing it or are you just guessing?